# Video resolution changing

Tags: video, resolution

When watching YouTube videos on my iMac, the screen intermittently switches to a lower resolution (the video gets blurry).  Then, after 5 or 10 seconds it switches back to normal resolution.  The symptom is the same even when I'm using Apple TV.  What's happening?

Comment: it's probably auto-sensing the download speed & changing resolution accordingly. Forcing it to the higher rez would probably give you periodic 'Buffering…' warnings. Check you can actually get data as fast as the stream needs. Wire up if you're using wifi.

Comment: Tetsujin,   That's a reasonable explanation.  I'm using DSL, and I'm becoming less and less satisfied with its performance.  I'll have to start looking into a speed  upgrade.  Thanks for responding!